# Separate lists of words for nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, dictionary

I am trying to parse a line and extract words found in [Wordnet database](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) 
but I don't know how to do it. For example, the index.adj file contains the following lines:

```
abactinal a 1 1 ! 1 0 01665972
abandoned a 2 1 & 2 1 01313004 01317231  
abashed a 1 1 & 1 1 00531628  
abasic a 1 2 \ + 1 0 02598608  
abatable a 1 2 & + 1 0 02288022  
abatic a 1 2 \ + 1 0 02598608  
abaxial a 1 2 ! ; 1 0 00002312  
abbatial a 1 2 \ + 1 0 02598768  
abbreviated a 2 1 & 2 1 01436432 01442597  
abdicable a 1 2 & + 1 0 02528048  
abdominal a 1 2 \ + 1 1 02934594  
abdominous a 1 2 & + 1 0 00986457
```

I am using .NET and C#, I have tried:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/^(\S+?)[\s%]/");
Match match = regex.Match(line);
```

I am looking for dictionary database for creating a data mining tool.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match in that string? The regex you have is a JavaScript style regex that will not work as expected in C#. If you plan to just match words, I'd use `@"\b\p{L}+\b"` regex and use `RegexMatches` to return the collection of words in a string.

Comment: sorry for the mistake ,i posted wrong text from file, can find regular expression for the lines i added now.some words contain _ also

Comment: This looks like a space delimited listing to me.  Why do you need regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need regex for this task since this input is a simple (white)space delimited text. Use this code:

```
var txt5 = "abactinal a 1 1 ! 1 0 01665972\r\nabandoned a 2 1 & 2 1 01313004 01317231\r\nabandon v 2 1 & 2 1 01313004 01317231  ";
var dic = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var lines = txt5.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     var cells = line.Split();
     switch (cells[1])
     { 
        case "a":
          dic.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("adjective", cells[0]));
          break;
        case "v":
          dic.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("verb", cells[0]));
          break;
        // Add more to cover all POS values
        default:
          break;
      }
 }
```

You can adapt it and work further.

Output:

[image]